# Не получается настроить удаленный интерпретатор на сервисе Beget, т.к. не пускает в каталог, пишет Access Denied

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

Пытался настроить дебаг и профилирование по руководству с Beget, остановился на том что не видит точки остановки и не запускает xDebug. Мое предположение, что дело в отсутствии удаленного интерпретатора. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно открыть доступ к каталогу сайта, для дальнейшей настройки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]